# Laravel multiple images uploader not executing

Tags: php, laravel

So I am trying to upload multiple images but I'm running into a problem when I select the images to upload and nothing is inserted into the database. No error is appearing so I'm unsure what is going on. Thank you.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'id' => 'integer',
            'images' => 'sometimes|image|nullable|max:5000'
        ]);

        if($request->hasFile('images'))
        {
            $images = $request->file('images');
            foreach ($images as $image)
            {
                $filenameWithExt = $image->getClientOriginalName();

                $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

                $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

                $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

                $path = $image->storeAs('public/image', $fileNameToStore);

                $images = new Images;
                $images->images = $fileNameToStore;
                $images->save();
            }
        }else {
            $fileNameToStore = null;
        }

        return back()->with('success_message','Images have been uploaded!');
    }
```

I thought it might be a problem using the images[] array in the blade which might be empty.

```
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ route('admin.images.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Images</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="file" name="images[]" class="form-control" multiple/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Look into upload_max_filesize,hasFile will return false if you are above the limit.

Comment: Both images are less than 150KB, so it shouldn't be exceeding the file size limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code if anyone wants to know.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if(!$this->validate($request, [
            'id' => 'integer',
            'images.*' => 'sometimes|image|nullable|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,webp|max:25000'
        ])) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('errors');
        }

        if($request->hasfile('images'))
        {
            foreach($request->file('images') as $image)
            {
                $filenameWithExt = $image->getClientOriginalName();

                $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

                $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

                $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

                $path = $image->storeAs('public/image', $fileNameToStore);

                $image = new Images;
                $image->images = $fileNameToStore;
                $image->save();
            }
        }

        return back()->with('Images have been uploaded!');
    }
```

Blade

```
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ route('admin.images.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Images</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="file" name="images[]" class="form-control" multiple/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @if($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                {{ $error }}<br>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First do this

```
 if(!$this->validate($request, [
            'upload.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,webp|max:25000',
        ])) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('errors');
        }
```

And in the blade

```
  @if($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        {{ $error }}<br>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endif
```

Multiple Images

```
 //MORE IMAGES
//this moves to public folder make changes if you are using app folder
        if($request->hasfile('upload'))
        {

           foreach($request->file('upload') as $i=>$image)
           {
            $image_nm = time().Str::random(32).$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $image->extension();
            $path = 'images/';
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i], $path.$image_nm);
            DB::table('images')->insert(
            [
                //

                'image' => 'images/'.$image_nm
            ]);
           }
        }
```

Comment: So the error I got was images must be an image which is probably coming from the name of the image input tag, when I remove the square brackets the error goes but it stills doesn't upload the images.

Comment: Yes I just want to upload multiple images, but nothing seems to happen for me.

Comment: is it doing what you want??

Comment: I have just tried your method and I am getting the same outcome doesn't seem to be inserting into the database.

Comment: So I've tweaked it a bit and the problem I'm getting now is it can't find the file directory I'm using a storage link to store the images. So I'm getting an error on ```move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i], $path.$image_nm); ```

Comment: Managed to get it working now thanks for your help really appreciate it.